# CartThrob {if error:your_field} conditional not working for item_options

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, error

Trying to use CartThrobs Inline Errors within a add_to_cart_form to validate a simple form with two fields. For the **price** field, the validation works, but for the **item_options[invoice_number]** it does not. Here is the code for the form and both fields.

```
    {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form 
        return="/portal/checkout/" secure_return="no"
        on_the_fly="true" allow_user_price="yes"
        title="Invoice Payment" quantity="1"
        error_handling="inline"
        rules:item_options[invoice_number]="required|is_numeric"
        rules:price="required|is_numeric"
        shipping_exempt="yes" tax_exempt="yes"
        }

        <div class="row">
            <div class="six columns">
                {if error:item_options[invoice_number]}<span class="error">{/if}
                <label for="item_options[invoice_number]">Invoice #</label>
                <input type="text" name="item_options[invoice_number]" class="textinput required" value="" />       
                {if error:item_options[invoice_number]}<p>Enter a value.</p></span>{/if}
            </div>
            <div class="six columns end">
                {if error:price}<span class="error">{/if}
                <label for="price">Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" data-symbol="$" class="textinput required dollar-amount" value="" />
                {if error:price}<p>Enter a numeric value.</p></span>{/if}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">              
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large spacebeforesm" value="Enter Payment Info &rarr;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

The error

```
Error
You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.
Parser State: Unexpected ‘[’ (MISC); expected RD in Template “portal/pay-invoice” on line 27.
```

Line 27 is the first **{if error:item_options[invoice_number]}**. It will render if I remove the brackets **{if error:item_options}** Does not matter what value I insert between the brackets, the page will not render.

[Documentation](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags/global_form_settings/index.html#if-erroryour_field) doesn't indicate that it won't work with item_options. And as often as the item_options is used, it is also likely that it works with item_options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Try adding quotes around the full tag so that you have:

```
{if "{error:item_options[invoice_number]}"}
```

Hopefully that should resolve it.